# exec name "templet_1h" is not defined

Tags: python, numpy, exec, eval

I'm trying to write a code with exec and eval function to read lists of variables from a numpy .npz file.

When I ran the code without defining it as a function def, the code worked. However, when I ran the code as a function, i.e. read_file_npz("file_address") , the python 3.7 kept pop up message saying that templet_1h was not defined.

```
def read_file_npz(file_names_2):
    import numpy as np
    Delete_elements=["arr_0"]

    evaluate_1= "templet_1h=np.load(\"./" +file_names_2+ ".npz\")";
    exec(evaluate_1)

    for i in (templet_1h.files):
        if not ( (i in Delete_elements) ):
            evaluate_2="global "+i;
            exec(evaluate_2)

            evaluate_2= i+"="+"templet_1h[\"" + i + "\"]";
            exec(evaluate_2)
```

What's wrong with the warning and how to modify it?

I tried to declear templet_1h before the code as list(), but then the warning became .files had no ... towards lists, as if evaluate_1 was never ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exec(evaluate_1, globals())` instead to use the global dictionary for global and local variables in `exec`.

The code adds the defined variable to the global dictionary. Adding it as local variable of a function is not possible.

Comment: I included evaluate_2="global "+i; after the code failed. I'm not sure why it didn't work. The error occured at for i in (templet_1h.files):

Comment: @user9976437 A `global` declaration only makes sense inside a function. Also it only relates to what is given as global dictionary to the execution environment. `exec` in some sense creates its own environment where global may mean something else.