# After running the function, the function became an ndarray

Tags: python, function, numpy, exec

I'm trying to write a code with exec and eval function to read lists of variables from a numpy .npz file.

See a previous post:
With Michael Butscher's help 
[exec name "templet_1h" is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53798843/exec-name-templet-1h-is-not-defined/53798879?noredirect=1#comment94447380_53798879)
, the function now is working. However, I met another awkward situation.

Before I execute the function type(read_file) was a function, after I excute the function type(read_file) became a class "numpy.ndarry".

Can someone help me to explain it a bit? How to solve it?

```
def read_file(file_names_2):
    global templet_1h
    import numpy as np
    Delete_elements=["arr_0"]
    evaluate_1= "templet_1h=np.load(\"./" +file_names_2+ ".npz\")";
    exec(evaluate_1,globals())
    for i in (templet_1h.files):
        if not ( (i in Delete_elements) ):
            evaluate_2= i+"="+"templet_1h[\"" + i + "\"]";
            exec(evaluate_2,globals())
    del templet_1h
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible explanation for this behavior is that you have a file called `read_file` that gets added to `templet_1h`.

When you loop through `templet_1h.files`, at some point, the following is being called:

```
evaluate_2= i+"="+"templet_1h[\"" + i + "\"]";
# this results in: read_file = templet_1h["read_file"]
```

When this is executed, it rebinds `read_file` to a numpy array in the global namespace instead of your function.

---

While there are ways to fix this issue, the *real* issue is that you shouldn't be using `exec` in this manner.  It is dangerous to execute arbitrary python code, and this particular snippet is *very* easy to abuse.  For example, if a user decides to make a filename `'np.argmax'`, you lose the ability to call the `argmax` function, the list goes on and on.

You should really use something like a dictionary to store a variable number of variables, rather than rely on dangerous behavior.

Answer (score 0):

a `numpy.ndarray` is a class type created by numpy for the purposes of calculations using numpy functions

To convert one to a most usable `list`:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.ndarray([1,2])
x = x.tolist()
```

Comment: I still don't understand why my function became an array after running it.

Comment: Because of `np.load` in `evaluate_1` and then your script calling it via `exec(evaluate_1,globals())`

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question?

Comment: @user3483203 He wanted explanation and the next few lines of code looks as though he is trying to manipulate a `list` object